# Ruby on Rails - user email verification page not exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to add confirmation of registration by clicking an activation email link. The email is sent, however when I click the link, it says the page does not exist. Deploying on heroku. 
Sample confirmation link:

```
/account_activations/g_dTGV1CbHip7w3w76pqCQ/edit?email=utn49585%40disaq.com
```

It looks like the app doesnt recognize this path. I checked, and the activation digest(g_dTGV1CbHip7w3w76pqCQ) is stored in the database. I have no idea what would cause such an error.

**account_activation.html.erb:**

```
Click the link below in order to activate your account
<%= edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email)%>
```

**account_activation.text.erb:**

```
Click the link below in order to activate your account
<%= edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email)%>
```

**routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root 'welcome#home'
get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
resources :users
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
end
```

The full github:
https://github.com/mateusz208345/Ror-My-App

Comment: Have you check the logs?

Comment: are you sure the link you clicked on was the most recently sent one?

Comment: The link to your repo is broken :( I can't see the rest of your app.

Comment: @RockwellRice yes.

Comment: @Gaston try now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change [this line](https://github.com/mateusz208345/Ror-My-App/blob/master/app/controllers/account_activations_controller.rb#L4) to:

```
user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
                ^^^
```

## Why?

`User.find(email: params[:email])` actually means: "find a user whose `id` is `{:email => "utn49585@disaq.com"}`.

## How did I figure it out?

I launched the application in development mode:

```
bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
bin/rails server
```

I created a user and saw in the logs that this email was rendered:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      /* Email styles need to be inline */
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    Click the link below in order to activate your account https://rails-tutorial-firel.c9users.io/account_activations/nK69XMp3floxtPhV1Jwskg/edit?email=utn49585%40disaq.com
  </body>
</html>
```

Then I went to: http://localhost:3000/account_activations/nK69XMp3floxtPhV1Jwskg/edit?email=utn49585%40disaq.com

And saw this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AccountActivationsController#edit 
Couldn't find User with 'id'={:email=>"utn49585@disaq.com"}
```

In production environments, such as Heroku, [`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` errors are treated as 404](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3ecffab324fc03df76eba91e4c2a7cb89a0580b9/activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb#L20) which might be misleading.

Changing the line I mentioned at the beginning of my answer fixed this particular error.